# Clear class not working if called from another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```html
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","noti");
$count=0;
if(!empty($_POST['add'])) {
 $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["subject"]);
 $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["comment"]);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (subject,comment) VALUES('" . $subject . "','" . $comment . "')";
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
$sql2="SELECT * FROM comments WHERE status = 0";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Facebook Like Header Notification in PHP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}

#main-header {
  height: 63px;
  background: #3D4752;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#bell {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#bell svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#bell .bubble {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 10px;
  min-width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background: #29AAE1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.noti-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 175px;
  max-height: 700px;
  left: -147px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}
.noti-container header {
  background: #707E8D;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.noti-container header h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.noti-container header a {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.noti-container:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #707E8D;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 130px;
}
.noti-container h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
.noti-container ul {
  max-height: 342px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
.noti-container ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style:none;
}
.noti-container ul li h4 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.noti-container ul li p {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.noti-container ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #29AAE1;
}
.noti-container ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.noti-container ul li .time, .noti-container ul li .clear {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  color: #A0A0A0;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
.noti-container ul li .clear {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.noti-container ul li.unread .time, .noti-container ul li.unread .clear {
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.noti-container ul li.unread .time:after, .noti-container ul li.unread .clear:after {
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #29AAE1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -12px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}
.noti-container ul li:hover .time {
  opacity: 0;
}
.noti-container ul li:hover .clear {
  opacity: 1;
}

.shadow-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/pMF6Mom.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.button-default {
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  -o-transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  transition: 0.25s ease-out 0.1s color;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

.show-notifications .notifications-count {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background: #3498db;
  color: #fefefe;
  font: normal 0.85em 'Lato';
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -2px;
  width: 16px;
}
</style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
   url: "view_notification.php",
   type: "POST",
   processData:false,
   success: function(data){
    $("#notification-count").remove();     
    $("#notification-latest").show();
    $("#list").html(data);
   },
   error: function(){}           
  });
  }
  
  
   
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header id="main-header">
  <div id="bell">


   <button type="button" class="button-default show-notifications active js-show-notifications" onclick="myFunction()">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="30" height="32" viewBox="0 0 30 32">
    <defs>
      <g id="icon-bell">
       <path class="path1" d="M15.143 30.286q0-0.286-0.286-0.286-1.054 0-1.813-0.759t-0.759-1.813q0-0.286-0.286-0.286t-0.286 0.286q0 1.304 0.92 2.223t2.223 0.92q0.286 0 0.286-0.286zM3.268 25.143h23.179q-2.929-3.232-4.402-7.348t-1.473-8.652q0-4.571-5.714-4.571t-5.714 4.571q0 4.536-1.473 8.652t-4.402 7.348zM29.714 25.143q0 0.929-0.679 1.607t-1.607 0.679h-8q0 1.893-1.339 3.232t-3.232 1.339-3.232-1.339-1.339-3.232h-8q-0.929 0-1.607-0.679t-0.679-1.607q3.393-2.875 5.125-7.098t1.732-8.902q0-2.946 1.714-4.679t4.714-2.089q-0.143-0.321-0.143-0.661 0-0.714 0.5-1.214t1.214-0.5 1.214 0.5 0.5 1.214q0 0.339-0.143 0.661 3 0.357 4.714 2.089t1.714 4.679q0 4.679 1.732 8.902t5.125 7.098z" />
      </g>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#000000">
     <use xlink:href="#icon-bell" transform="translate(0 0)"></use>
    </g>
  </svg>
 
    <div class="notifications-count js-count" id="notification-count"><?php if($count>0) { echo $count; } ?></div>
</button>
   
    <div class="noti-container" id="notification-latest">
      <header>
        <h3>Notifications</h3><a id="clearAll" href="#">Clear All</a>
      </header>
      <h2>No new notifications</h2>
      <ul id="list">
        
       
      </ul>
      <div class="shadow-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
 
  
    
     
   
 
 <?php if(isset($message)) { ?> <div class="error"><?php echo $message; ?></div> <?php } ?>


 <?php if(isset($success)) { ?> <div class="success"><?php echo $success;?></div> <?php } ?>

  <form name="frmNotification" id="frmNotification" action="" method="post" >
   <div id="form-header" class="form-row">Add New Message</div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label">Subject:</div><div class="error" id="subject"></div>
    <div class="form-element">
     <input type="text"  name="subject" id="subject" required>
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-label">Comment:</div><div class="error" id="comment"></div>
    <div class="form-element">
     <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-element">
     <input type="submit" name="add" id="btn-send" value="Submit">
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 var bell = $('#bell');
var clearBtn = $('.clear');

var unread = $('.unread').length;
var listLength = $('li').length;
var bubble = $('.bubble');
var container = $('.noti-container');

bell.click(function(e) {
 if( container.is(":hidden") ){
  container.fadeIn(300).css('top', '50px');
 } else {
  container.fadeOut(300).css('top', '30px');
 }
 
 e.stopPropagation();
});




clearBtn.click(function(e) {                        // not working 
 listItem = $(this).parents('li');

 if (listItem.hasClass('unread')) {
  unread --;  
 }
 listLength --;
 $(this).parents('li').slideUp(300);
 
 e.stopPropagation();
});



$('#clearAll').click(function(e) {               //working
 $('li').slideUp(300);
 unread = 0;
 listLength = 0;
 counter();
 e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
 container.fadeOut(300).css('top', '30px');
});

container.click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

My clear class was working fine when i was not calling it from another file.
But now i am using another file to show the clear class. Actually it is attached with the view-notification file so with every entry in index.php creates a notification in database which i am calling through view-notification.php

Here is my view-notification.php:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","noti");
$sql="UPDATE comments SET status=1 WHERE status=0"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$sql="select * from comments ORDER BY id DESC limit 5";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$response='';
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$response = $response . " <li class='unread'>" .
"<h4>". $row["subject"] . "</h4>" . 
"<p>" . $row["comment"]  . "</p><span class='time'>8:01pm</span>
 <span class='clear'>Clear</span>" .      // the clear class calling
"</li>";
}


if(!empty($response)) {
print $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: are you worry about working of this <span class='clear'>Clear</span>"?

Comment: yes its working if i keep it in index.php file but stops to work if called from view-notification file

Comment: Place all your CSS in single file style.css and then call it using link tag in you html, I believe it should work

Comment: Ok so now i got it the listlength value is passed as 0 everytime as i am using ajaz to call the value but how to get the actual list length